# Why can only certain characters be printed in bold?

Tags: bash, printing, terminal, ansi-colors

I have been working on a program that prints bold text in the terminal in some cases, but I have been wondering, why are certain characters like *, #, and ~ not printed in bold? Also, is there anyway to get them to be printed in bold. I already know how to use escape sequences to do that, but is there some other way? Here is a code example:

```
#This isn't bold:  
print "\033[94m####\033[1m"

#But this is:
print "\033[94mHello\033[1m"
```

**Edit**: I'm dumb. The above code should be this instead:

```
print "\033[94;1m####\033[0m"
```

Comment: How are you attempting to print?

Comment: Could you post some code/method you're using to print bold text?

Comment: What OS are you on, and what shell are you using?  I'll bet that different shells or OS's handle this differently.

Comment: @SethMMorton I am running the raspberry pi variant of Linux.

Comment: @SethMMorton you're definitely right.. exactly zero of my interpreters print bold text using this syntax

Comment: I have added the bash tag to this because the question isn't really about python at all... you would see the same results if just doing `echo "\033[94m####\033[1m"` on the command line.  Hopefully this will attract someone that knows about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the bold SGR command *after* the text. You must print the bold command *before* the text for it to have an effect:

```
bold='\033[1m'
blue='\033[94m'
normal='\033[m'

print bold+'Hello'+normal  # This prints in bold
print bold+'###'+normal    # So does this
```

Reference:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf

Comment: Maybe. What sort of terminal do you use?

Comment: When I the above code in an LXterminal window, I get a bold "hello" **and** a bold "###". I don't know why you'd get otherwise.